# Norton Antivirus notification, but no Norton installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus

I've never had Norton Antivirus installed, but recently I there was a very brief yellow notification in the lower right corner that showed 'Norton Antivirus...'  and then disappeared before I read anything more than that.

I'm using windows 7.  I checked the registry for anything named Norton, but it only found an entry for NortonSystemInfo in the following key folders:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectDraw\Compatibility\NortonSystemInfo`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw\Compatibility\NortonSystemInfo`

Obviously neither of those are Norton Antivirus.

Where did this notification come from and should I be concerned?

Comment: Probably [rougeware](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/13869/Rogueware).

Comment: I've run Malwarebytes and it did not find anything.  I'm also running a scan with ESET NOD32 Antivirus and Spybot Search and Destroy.  So far nothing has been found.

Comment: Neither scan found anything.

Comment: those entries are internal Windows settings. Ignore them.

Comment: Did you do a Full System scan using MBAM and Eset? Not the quick scan.

Comment: No, but I'll do that next and comment with the results.

Comment: Both full scans found nothing amiss.  The definition files were both properly updated before the scans.  I also ran sfc /scannow and it found no integrity issues.  Oh, and I updated Spybot Search and Destroy and ran it again.  It also found no issues.

Comment: My windows security patches are up to date as well.  I could produce a hijackthis log, if that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 settings are internal Windows settings for application compatibility. Ignore them, they don't have any negative effect on you.

Comment: I'm not worried about the NortonSystemInfo entries.  I'm concerned about the popup that said something about Norton Antivirus.  I only mentioned those because I searched the registry and those were the only keys that had the word 'Norton' in them.  This has not happened a second time, so far, but it was odd that I'd get a Norton Antivirus notification without having it installed.  I've run every test I can think of, short of Tron and they all came back negative.

Comment: Also, it was a taskbar notification, not a website popup, if that wasn't clear.